# Mysql query in gas ORM

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

1. this is  i am getting

   ```
   SELECT * FROM (`lkt_messages`) WHERE `sender_id` = '1' AND `receiver_id` = '2' OR `sender_id` = '2' OR `receiver_id` = '1' ORDER BY `added_on` DESC
   ```

I want like this

```
    SELECT * FROM (`lkt_messages`) WHERE `sender_id` = '1' AND `receiver_id` = '2' OR `sender_id` = '2' AND `receiver_id` = '1' ORDER BY `added_on` DESC
```

I write the query below.

```
    $cls=MESSAGES_TBL;
            $id= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $condition_query=array('sender_id'=>$replymsg_id,'receiver_id'=>$id);
            $condition_query1=array('sender_id'=>$id,'receiver_id'=>$replymsg_id);

            $data=$cls::where($condition_query)->or_where($condition_query1);

             $result=$data->order_by('added_on', 'DESC')->all();

            return $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following change should work:

```
$condition_query = "(sender_id = $replymsg_id and receiver_id = $id)";

$condition_query1 = "(sender_id = $id and receiver_id = $replymsg_id)";

$data = $cls::where($condition_query)->or_where($condition_query1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`lkt_messages`) 
WHERE (`sender_id` = '1' AND `receiver_id` = '2') 
OR (`sender_id = '2' AND `receiver_id` = '1') 
ORDER BY `added_on` DESC
```